# Check if a User is Logged On In a PHP Login System

Tags: php, html, authentication

I'm relatively new to PHP and have been making a PHP login system. It works fine and all, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner and more efficient way to check if a user is logged in. At the current moment my code looks like this:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
Echo "*Whole bunch of HTML*";
}
else{
header("location:index.php");
end();
}
```

I want to make it to where the if statement checks if the user is logged in and nothing more, rather than having the if statement check if the user is logged in then displaying the page within in the if statement. Is this possible?

Comment: `include('/path/to/yourhtml.html');`

Comment: your statments is clean enough to check sessions

Comment: Hint: `if (!isset($_SESSION...)) exit;`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing things ok. But here is what I do for my code:

```
function checklogin() {
    if (!$this->isLoggedIn())
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


function isLoggedIn() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_SESSION['user_email'])) {

        if( !$this->isTimeOut() )
            return false;

        $where = array(
            'id' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
            'email' => $_SESSION['user_email']
        );

        //this is database class method
        $value['data'] = $dataBaseClass->login_access($where);

        if ($value['data'] != FALSE && $_SESSION['user_id'] == $value['data']->id && $_SESSION['user_email'] == $value['data']->email) {

            return true;
        }
        /*
          username or userlevel not exist or s_ecryption session invalid
          User not logged in.
         */
        else
            return false;
    }
    /**
     * cookie check for user login || you can escape this
     */
        else if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie_key']) && $_COOKIE['cookie_key'] != '') {

        $cookie_key = $_COOKIE['cookie_key'];
        $where = array(
            'cookie_key' => $cookie_key
        );
        $user_data = $databaseClass->login_access($where);

        if (!empty($user_data)) {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_data->id;
            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $user_data->email;

            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Make a library/functions file, write above code, include that file in class files you need and call the function.

Hope this helps.